# How to write the code in VB from MS access

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Working on this database in MS Access and tried to put it in VB.net..

in my MS access the "Replace" work as what it is suppose to do. but when i tried it in vb.net "Replace" function does not work.. some Advice they give is that to work it around with LEFT and RIGHT function with also LEN in it.. how could i do it? I tried by I failed.. 
This in MS ACCESS: How could i Write in VB?

```
 Replace(Replace(Trim([f_7Synonyms].[SynSpecies]),"var. ",""),"f. ","") AS Speciest
```

Comment: Just tell what u want do in VB.NET..........VB.NET is different MS ACCESS is different.

Comment: What do you mean "function doesn't work"?  Is it giving incorrect results, and error, etc.?

Comment: I mean about function doesn't work sir is that it is giving error in VB.net. I really want to do, is that that line of code in MS access could be transform into another line of code.. So that i would not use the Replace function. instead i go another way with the same result. that is replacing all the "var." and "f." in SynSpecies Column.. :( I'm sorry sir.. I'm really new at VB... :(